# SharePoint 2010 application crashes - Attempted to read or write protected memory?

Tags: administration, iis

Often, we are facing the below issue with SharePoint 2010.

System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
 at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.GetEnumerator()
 at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelTriggerCollection.Initialize()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

any help    ?

HI Karthikeyan, let me know if it fixed your issue.

Comment: When / Where is this happening (i.e. every page, certain pages, etc).  Are there custom web parts deployed and activated on these pages?

Comment: we have only 10 pages in our environment, pages are rendering fine. This issue occurs suddenly and application crashes. I could find any other clue on the ULS but may be verify the eventviewer for further details.

Answer (score 3):

Have you verified there are no other memory issues?  You can run something like Memtest to validate it's not the modules.

Are there any other related items in the logs, like excessive AppPool Recycles, etc?

**EDIT**
MS has a few KB articles:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;946517

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923028

Additionally if those hotfixes don't work, I would start some long running PerfMon session to capture CPU and Mem stats.  Probably include your app pools in there. When the problem occurs again, see if there is any correlations to your perfMon captures.  You want to see if you have large Memory spikes, and what is causing them (CPU, App Pools, etc). My guess would be your AppPool(s) are sucking up a lot of memory, if so, you can limit them in the AppPool settings so they recycle earlier. Additionally if you any caching enabled, you will want to review those settings.

Comment: other are no other clue, may will give a memory test just to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Event ID 7076 -

Office SharePoint Server "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is
often an indication that other memory is corrupt. "
"System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This
is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
...

Event ID 6398 -

Windows SharePoint Services 3 NERA-WPWFE1
"Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerAdministrationServiceJob
""cddd50c5-bf98-4496-85b5-d1c755e4dca7 "
"Exception from HRESULT: 0x80005006

Event ID 6482 -

"Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.ExcelServerSharedWebServiceInstance
""3ff29932-af40-4296-b012-eb71dee2c40e ""Attempted to read or write protected
memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. ""
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This
is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Some customers also reported that the IIS MMC stops responding and a restart of IIS is required to resolve the problem.

After some research we found that all these problems were caused by a problem in the IIS ADSI providers. A hotfix to resolve this issue is meanwhile available:

946517 - FIX: You may be unable to manage IIS 6.0 by using Server Manager if two threads access IIS 6.0 at the same time

Comment: will check and let you know the result.